# Access Variables Across Shiny Apps

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny-server hosting multiple shiny apps. A lot of these apps use the same data (eg data1, data2, data3, etc) read in via read.csv() when the app is first loaded. Some of these csv files are relatively large and it can slow down the app start-up process.

Is there a way to have this data stored in server memory somehow as global variables that all apps can access without having to load on app startup?

```
library(shiny)
data1 <- read.csv(file = 'some-data1.csv')
data2 <- read.csv(file = 'some-data2.csv')
data3 <- read.csv(file = 'some-data3.csv')
ui <- fluidPage()
server <- function(input, output) {}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: When you get the answer I want to know also!

Comment: If it's just about gaining more speed, you could either use the [`vroom` package](https://vroom.r-lib.org/) that should be about 50 times faster than `read.csv`. Or you could avoid parsing the data completely by serialising them with `saveRDS`. - But I can understand why sharing the data across apps would even be better.

Comment: The information in Shiny documentation leads me to believe that you can't share object across different applications because each application uses a different R process. Shiny says, "between the R processes, no objects are shared." [See more here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html) But I'm **no expert**! Here is more on [shiny scalability and performance](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/231874748-Scaling-and-Performance-Tuning-in-RStudio-Connect)